# jQuery TinySort Problems

Tags: jquery

I am working on a script that will utilize the jQuery TinySort Extension to sort divs according to a dropdown change selection.

For some reason I can't get it to work properly.

JS Code:

```
$("#sort").change(function(){
            var column = $(this).val();

            console.log(column);
            $(".r1_contenders_videos_wrapper .wcje_judges_video").tsort("div[class*='" + column + "']", {
                order:"asc"
            });
        })
```

Example of HTML Markup for sorting:

```
<div class="wcje_judges_video">
    <div class="judges_video_thmb">
            <a href="http://url.com/watch/87ujuhy77676">
                <img class="video_img" width="200px" src="link_to_image" alt="Test User"/>
                <img class="wcje_play" src="/assets/images/play-btn-sm.png" />
                <img class="wcje_flag" src="/assets/images/flags_lg/5.png" />
            </a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="wcje_video_song_title">I want it all</h3>
    <p class="contender_name">Dennis M.</p>
    <p class="contender_country">United States</p>
</div>

<div class="wcje_judges_video">
    <div class="judges_video_thmb">
            <a href="http://url.com/watch/87ujuhy77676">
                <img class="video_img" width="200px" src="link_to_image" alt="Test User"/>
                <img class="wcje_play" src="/assets/images/play-btn-sm.png" />
                <img class="wcje_flag" src="/assets/images/flags_lg/5.png" />
            </a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="wcje_video_song_title">Not today</h3>
    <p class="contender_name">Chris S.</p>
    <p class="contender_country">Canada</p>
</div>
```

Select Option Markup:

```
<select name="sort" id="sort">
                <option value="contender_name">Alphabetical</option>
                <option value="wcje_video_song_title">Song</option>
                <option value="contender_country">Country</option>
            </select>
```

So basically I have the value of the option selects to match the div class names of what I want to sort the divs on.. but can't get it to work. No errors or anything just doesn't work... any idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

jquery.tinysort is targeted at child elements in a parent container. <li> items in a <ul>, a range of items of the same class in a parent <div> and so on.

Place your wcje_judges_video-divs in a container

```
<div id="video_container">
..your HTML here
</div>
```

.. and the following works :

```
$("#sort").change(function(){
  var column = $(this).val();
  $("div#video_container>.wcje_judges_video").tsort('.'+column, {order:"asc"});
});
```